# Applying multiple filters to a collection in a thrush in Clojure

Tags: clojure

The following code

```
(let [coll [1 2 3 4 5]
      filters [#(> % 1) #(< % 5)]]
  (->> coll
       (filter (first filters))
       (filter (second filters))))
```

Gives me

```
(2 3 4)
```

Which is great, but how do I apply all the filters in coll without having to explicitly name them?

There may be totally better ways of doing this, but ideally I'd like to know an expression that can replace (filter (first filters)) (filter (second filters)) above.

Thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Clojure 1.3 has a new [`every-pred`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/every-pred) function, which you could use thusly:

```
(filter (apply every-pred filters) coll)
```

Answer (score 13):

This should work :-

```
(let [coll [1 2 3 4 5]
      filters [#(> % 1) #(< % 5)]]
  (filter (fn [x] (every? #(% x) filters)) coll)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't say I'm very proud of the following, but at least it works and allows for infinite filters:

```
(seq 
  (reduce #(clojure.set/intersection 
          (set %1) 
          (set %2)) (map #(filter % coll) filters)))
```

If you can use sets in place of seqs it would simplify the above code as follows:

```
(reduce clojure.set/intersection (map #(filter % coll) filters))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(let [coll [1 2 3 4 5]
      filters [#(> % 1) #(< % 5)]]
  (reduce (fn [c f] (filter f c)) coll filters))
```